# Can directive isolated scope be used inside directive for calculations

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If there is a directive defined can the scope passed to it through attributes, defined on it, be used inside this directive to get needed results for usage in template? i.e. I have such directive

```
var carAuction = angular.module('carAuction');

carAuction
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope)
    {
        var car = {
            comments: []
        };

        car.comments.push({
            comment: 'Ok car',
            rating: 1
        });

        car.comments.push({
            comment: 'Nice car.',
            rating: 2
        });

        car.comments.push({
            comment: 'Awesome car!',
            rating: 3
        });

        $scope.car = car;
    })
    .directive('carCommentRaiting', function()
    {
        return
        {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
            scope:
            {
                value: '=value',
                maxValue: '=max-value'
            }
        };
    })
    .filter('range', function()
    {
        return function(input, total)
        {
            total = parseInt(total);

            for (var i=1; i<=total; i++)
            {
                input.push(i);
            }

            return input;
        };
    });
```

In html part I have

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="comment in car.comments">
        Rating: <car-comment-raiting value="comment.rating" max-value="10"></car-comment-raiting>
    </div>
</div>
```

**template.html**

```
<div>
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li ng-repeat="n in [] | range:value"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

And I want to pass additional value to the template which should be calculated as `maxValue - value`. Haven't found any example describing that. Thought about using `link` property, but description tells, that it is used for other purpose.

**UPD:**
I was able to fix it with

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
    scope:
    {
        value: '=',
        maxValue: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope)
    {
        $scope.calculated = $scope.maxValue - $scope.value;
    }
};
```

but for some reason it doesn't work all the time. One time it works and the other time `calculated` variable is `null`.

Comment: please post `template.html` or Fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All calculations must be done inside a direcitve link function or in controller. 
Here is example with directive:

```
.directive('carCommentRaiting', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: 'path/to/template.html',
            scope: {
                value: '=value',
                maxValue: '=max-value'
            },
            link : function(scope, element, attr) {
                 scope.calculated = scope.maxValue - scope.value;
                 /// watch value to update calculated on value update:
                 scope.$watch('value', function(newValue){
                      scope.calculated = scope.maxValue - newValue;
                 });
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Tried in controller, but didn't solve the issue, but link property was the magic I was looking for. Also there is no need to calculate outside `$watch`. Thank you.